# Matrix with GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: github, matrix, github-actions

I'm developing a GHA workflow that will update an account yaml file for Cloud Custodian. The first job in the workflow builds the matrix based on the repo it is running from,

```
jobs:
  setup-matrix:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: '${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}'
    steps:
      - name: Set matrix
        id: set-matrix
        run: >
          echo "Setting up matrix..."

          if [[ "${{ github.repository }}" ==
          "newscorp-ghfb/nct-cloud-custodian-sandbox" ]]; then
            MATRIX_JSON='[
              { "infrastructure": "gcp", "env": "sandbox", "business_unit": "sandbox" },
              { "infrastructure": "aws", "env": "sandbox", "business_unit": "sandbox", "aws_region": "us-east-1" },
              { "infrastructure": "aws", "env": "sandbox", "business_unit": "nna", "aws_region": "us-east-1" },
              { "infrastructure": "aws", "env": "sandbox", "business_unit": "move", "aws_region": "us-west-2" },
              { "infrastructure": "aws", "env": "sandbox", "business_unit": "nuk", "aws_region": "us-west-2" }
            ]'
          elif [[ "${{ github.repository }}" ==
          "newscorp-ghfb/nct-cloud-custodian" ]]; then
            MATRIX_JSON='[
              { "infrastructure": "onegcp", "env": "prod", "business_unit": "nna" },
              { "infrastructure": "aws", "env": "prod", "business_unit": "nna", "aws_region": "us-east-1" },
              { "infrastructure": "aws", "env": "prod", "business_unit": "move", "aws_region": "us-west-2" },
              { "infrastructure": "aws", "env": "prod", "business_unit": "nuk", "aws_region": "us-west-2" }
            ]'
          else
            echo "Unknown repository"
            exit 1
          fi

          echo "${MATRIX_JSON}" > matrix.json
          echo "Matrix JSON stored as an artifact."
      - name: Upload Matrix Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: matrix-artifact
          path: matrix.json

      - name: Display Job Status Code
        run: |
          echo "Job Status Code: $?"
```

The second job in the workflow will bring on the created matrix and process each row of values 1 row at a time. Here is a snippet of that code,

```
  new-autoAccountUpdate:
    needs: setup-matrix
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: write
      pull-requests: write
    
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 1

    steps:
      - name: Download Matrix Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: matrix-artifact
          path: .

      - name: Display Matrix Context
        run: |
          echo "Current Matrix Context: ${{ toJson(matrix) }}"
  
      - name: List Files in Working Directory
        run: ls -al

      - name: Display Matrix
        run: cat matrix.json

      - name: Creating Temp Branch
        run: echo "Creating temporary branch..."
      - name: Create Temp branch
        run: |
          echo "Matrix values:"
          echo "Business Unit: ${{ matrix.business_unit }}"
          echo "Infrastructure: ${{ matrix.infrastructure }}"
          echo "Environment: ${{ matrix.env }}"
          echo "AWS Region: ${{matrix.aws_region}}"
          BRANCH_NAME="${{ matrix.business_unit }}_${{ matrix.infrastructure }}_${{ matrix.env }}_update"

          echo "Branch name: $BRANCH_NAME"

          uses: peterjgrainger/action-create-branch@v2.0.1

          env:
            GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          with:
            "${{ matrix.business_unit }}_${{ matrix.infrastructure }}_${{ matrix.env }}_update"
          if: success()
```

The output for the Display Matrix step looks great, I used this command to get the output, run: cat matrix.json

```
[
    { "infrastructure": "gcp", "env": "sandbox", "business_unit": "sandbox" },
    { "infrastructure": "aws", "env": "sandbox", "business_unit": "sandbox", "aws_region": "us-east-1" },
    { "infrastructure": "aws", "env": "sandbox", "business_unit": "nna", "aws_region": "us-east-1" },
    { "infrastructure": "aws", "env": "sandbox", "business_unit": "move", "aws_region": "us-west-2" },
    { "infrastructure": "aws", "env": "sandbox", "business_unit": "nuk", "aws_region": "us-west-2" }
  ] echo Matrix JSON stored as an artifact.
```

If I try to display the rox that I am working on I get a null value. Used this command, echo "Current Matrix Context: ${{ toJson(matrix) }}"

And every reference to a martix element such as ${{ matrix.business_unit }} is display as blank.

What am I doing wrong here? Benn banging my heads against the desk all afternoon trying to figure it out and got nowhere.

Any suggestions or ideas as how I can resolve this.

TIA...

My expectations are to be able to extract the individual entries from the matrix.